# Full text search library for multilingual content

Tags: full-text-search, search-engine, multilingual

What is a good full-text search library (free/licensed) that works well with multilingual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) has analyzers for a wide variety of languages. That only works, of course, if you know which language each document is in: either give them a language tag or use a [language guesser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395478/best-java-library-for-automatic-language-identification).

(Though if you want to do cross-lingual retrieval with machine translation in the pipeline, you're on your own, I'm afraid.)

Comment: Thanks for the language guesser suggestion. I think it would be sufficient for my case.

Comment: @Plelilune: mind you, language guessing works well on documents, but on short queries it can be error-prone. For queries, letting the user select the language (and defaulting to "find documents in all languages") might be the sensible option.